# how to grow the height of the data element dynamically in grid?

Tags: reporting, birt

I am using BIRT 4.3. I have placed a data element in the grid. The data element is mapped to a database column. The data element should have fixed width and it has to grow it's height dynamically based on the length of the data and the data should be wrapped in the data element. How can we achieve this? Why is the data not being wrap automatically? Am i doing something wrong? I have not entered any values in height and width properties. I left them to default. I am using only pdf reports.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a function for this, as described in this thread: http://www.birt-exchange.org/forum/index.php?/topic/19827-how-do-i-use-word-wrap-in-report-design/

Comment: ok will try with that. The example says that we should have white spaces but my text does not contain white spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Finally ended up in writing my own script for wrapping a long single word which does not have spaces at all or may have spaces. Thanks for your time and help.